# IE8 is clicking through a div, why?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, z-index

Check out here:

If you click on "Create Account" or "Login", and try to fill in the forms in IE8 (ignore the fact that placeholders aren't working.. that'll be fixed very soon), you'll notice that you keep clicking through the div to the links below, making it near-impossible to fill out the form.

I've been looking up the IE z-index issues but nothing I try is working. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! The line 'background: none' on the input was causing this. Damn IE. I just made the background the same colour as the surrounding div so it looks the same.